# C# - GC friendly pointer room up

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Supposed I have a large Bitmap stored in a BitmapImage object:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
```

For whatever reason I need to add some more pointers:

```
BitmapImage p1 = img;
BitmapImage p2 = img;
BitmapImage p3 = img;
```

Now, if I don't need img anymore I set it to null pointer:

```
img = null;
```

Is that enough so that the GC rooms it up correctly? Or is it also necessary to do the following:

```
p1 = null;
p2 = null;
p3 = null;
```

Comment: You can do a memory profiling and see the results

Comment: The garbage collector can only destroy an object when *all* references (aka pointers) to the object disappeared *or* those references are a member of objects that are also eligible for collection.  The latter clause is the normal way collection happens, explicitly setting a reference to null should only be necessary in unusual corner cases.  Which do exist in the specific case of BitmapImage, Microsoft made a gross design mistake by not making it disposable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the output of memory allocated for the process the memory is released only when the last pointer is set to null. I used a big List because empty BitmapImage was very small in memory.

Interactive C#:

```
> Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             var l = Enumerable.Repeat(123, 10000000).ToList();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             System.GC.Collect();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
140423168
270663680
207835136
>             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             System.GC.Collect();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
207761408
207761408
> Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             var p1 = l;
207831040
> Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
207851520
> var p2 = l;
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             var p3 = l;
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
208273408
208273408

> Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             l = null;
.             System.GC.Collect();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             p1 = null;
.             System.GC.Collect();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             p2 = null;
.             System.GC.Collect();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
.             p3 = null;
.             System.GC.Collect();
.             Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64);
208314368
208314368
208314368
208314368
141033472
```

Comment: Thanks for the big example! My hope was, that p1, p2 and p3 are only pointer to the img pointer. But if they are also direct pointers to the object, setting img to null is really not enough.